# I just installed Arch with grub2. When I boot it doesn't launch grub

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I am just dual-booted my computer with Windows 8.1 and Arch. I have windows on a 120GB SSD and arch is on a 2TB HDD with ~half partitioned for windows storage space and the other half partitioned for arch. I have a 2MB partition for grub on the HDD as well as a 960GB partition mounted at `/` and a 100MB partition mounted at `/boot`. My issue is that, even after installing grub without a hitch, when I boot from my hard drive it says that there is no OS and to insert a device or reboot my computer. I have gone through and looked at all the forums. I even tried starting from the top multiple times. No matter what I try I can't get it to boot into arch. When the live-disk that I used to install is plugged in and I boot to the HDD then the live-disk starts. If I select `Boot from an existing OS` on the live-disk then it boots back into the live disk. How do I get grub working?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the boot options first. If boot option is set to UEFI then you will not be able to make your system dual boot,  and you will need to go with the UEFI install options.